# Did Google migrate old Google app to Google cloud?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am a company admin and have a simple Java app (no backend, just several mostly static pages assembled through tiles) deployed since Google started the app engine. The site went down a couple of days ago. When I log in and go Admin/App Engine Apps page the app shows with the status "Always on". But it's not running and the message on top states "This feature will be moving to the Google Developers Console in Q2 2015. Follow these instructions to get the new permissions you'll need." Instructions are https://cloud.google.com/developers/articles/best-practices-for-configuring-permissions-on-gcp/#h.bgs0oxofvnoo.

But when I go to the dev console under my account - nothing is there. Called support (we are paying for some Google services) and they can't say anything except that now we need to sign up for Silver support at Google Cloud to talk to anybody there. But I am able to configure and deal with the app - I just can't find it anywhere! Any pointers will be hugely appreciated.

Comment: Go to https://console.developers.google.com to see if your project is there first

Comment: No, it's not - there is nothing there. That was my question -  what happened to the app?

Comment: Then go to https://appengine.google.com to see if there is anything

Comment: Thank you for responding. It was deployed under different account; that's why there was no info under the account I was in. I had to go to the other account and make the primary account an owner. But things were still pretty weird - the app wasn't deployed and there was a message that it's "disabled or waiting to be delete". There were no explanation why. I tried to deploy a newer version, which I verified is functional, but still no success - deployments would fail. Anyway, it's all resolved (I deployed under a different project name and deleted the old one). But this sure doesn't look easy..